# How to stream video in a loop via RTP using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtp

Given a file input.mp4, how can I use ffmpeg to stream it in a loop to some rtp://xxx:port?

I was able to do something similar for procedurally generated audio based on the ffmpeg streaming guides, but I was unable to find a video example:

```
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i aevalsrc="sin(400*2*PI*t)" -ar 44100 -f mulaw -f rtp rtp://xxx:port
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
ffmpeg -re -fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -f rtp rtp://xxx:port
```

Comment: error: "At least one output file must be specified"

Comment: -stream_loop did the trick but I had to change a few things:
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://xxx

Comment: @SagiMann, excellent that it's now solved. Yes it slipped mind that after the `-i input.mp4` must be followed by  `[media options]` (_ie:_ codec, frame or bit rates, quality, etc) then finally your output file name/type.